# Wordpress custom post type permalink - Insert before pages

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, custom-post-type

I am utilizing a custom post type to create landing pages that act as mini-sites. I would like to be able to allow these landing pages to show pages from the whole site while maintaining their CPT name in the URL structure. Example:

Normal URL for any page: `http://www.site.com/sub-page`
Landing Page: `http://www.site.com/landing`

Desired outcome from navigation on http://www.site.com/landing/landing-abc:
`http://www.site.com/landing/sub-page`
`www.site.com/landing/sub-page` and `www.site.com/sub-page` are the same page, just displayed at two different URLs

Comment: Why? What are you hoping to get out of this?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert The landing pages are set up to be the home page of a distributor (branded with their logo, etc). The goal is to have pages from the site shown under their own url structure. Is this a better task for multi-sites or something of that nature?

Comment: I think so, yes.  You'd want the subpages to be branded as well,right?  So they wouldn't be exactly the same

Comment: They really just need to retain their own header/footer and pull the same content from specific pages into a url structure that has their name as a sub folder.

Comment: It might be easier to use subdomains (`http://client.site.com/`) and conditionally load different headers and footers depending on what URL the site is being viewed on.